# Understand the type of param in void f(const T& param)

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, constants, auto

Reference: Effective Modern C++ Item 4.

https://github.com/BartVandewoestyne/Effective-Modern-Cpp/blob/master/Item04_Know_how_to_view_deduced_types/runtime_output02.cpp

```
class Widget {};

template<typename T>                // template function to
void f(const T& param)              // be called
{
}

std::vector<Widget> createVec()    // factory function
{
    std::vector<Widget> vw;
    Widget w;
    vw.push_back(w);
    return vw;
}

int main()
{
    const auto vw = createVec();        // init vw w/factory return

    if (!vw.empty()) {
      f(&vw[0]);                        // call f
      // ...
    }
}
```

Based on the book, the type of both `T` and `param` are as follows respectively:

```
T = class Widget const *
param = class Widget const * const &
```

I have problems to understand why the `param` is the given type with the `f(const T& param)` defined above.

Here is my understanding,

```
T = class Widget const *
```

So `f(const T& param)` becomes the following:

`f(const const Widget * & param)`.

Why the real type of `param` is `Widget const * const &` instead?

Comment: `T =     class Widget const *`
`param = class Widget const *`
on Visual Studio 2017 RC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Question> Why the real type of param is Widget const * const & instead?

I'm not really an expert but... because `T` is a pointer and if you write `const T &` (that is `T const &` because the rule is that `const` apply on the element on the left or on the element on the right in there isn't an element on the left) you are imposing that the full `T` type, so the pointer, is constant.

And to impose that the pointer is constant, you have to impose `cont` on the left of the `*`.

In brief: `const T &` is equivalent to `T const &`; with `T` that is `const Widget *`, `T const &` become `const Widget * const &` or, if you prefer, `Widget const * const &`

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing about **const pointer** and **pointer to const** (and then **const pointer to const**).

Note the position of `*` and `const`. e.g. `Widget const *` is a non-const pointer to const (`Widget`), `Widget * const` is a const pointer to non-const (`Widget`), `Widget const * const` is a const pointer to const (`Widget`).

For `T = Widget const *`, which is non-const pointer to const; note that for `const T`, `const` is qualified on `T` i.e. the pointer itself, not on the object pointed to, then `const T` will be `Widget const * const`.